# Is there a limit on the number of EBS Snapshots we can archive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, aws-backup

Recently, AWS started offering archival of the EBS snapshots. Here is their press release: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-ebs-snapshots-archive/

I started archiving snapshots which send them to S3 Glacier and them it seems like I am hitting a limit as I am getting the following message:

Max number of archived snapshots per volume reached

Anyone know what the limit is on the number of archives I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation there is an adjustable limit of 25 archived snapshots per volume.

You can request to increase this value.

[image]

---

Reference:

[Amazon Elastic Block Store endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ebs-service.html)